# Gitlab api upload in python

Tags: python, api, gitlab

According to official documentation curl request is

```
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: 9koXpg98eAheJpvBs5tK" --form "file=@dk.png" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v3/projects/5/uploads
```

I change it to python and get

```
import requests

headers = {

    'PRIVATE-TOKEN': 'my_token'
}
form = {
    'file': '@gaa.pdf'
}
print(requests.post('https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/4067343/uploads', headers=headers, form=form))
```

And I have response like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/k/pro/rat/try.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(requests.post('https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/4067343/uploads', headers=headers, form=form))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 112, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'form'
```

What should I do to have response with link instead of mistake?

Comment: You forgot to mention what problem you are facing.

Comment: Added, thank you))))

Comment: Is the Token in the `wget` command truncated or is it your real token ?

Comment: that is fake one from documents, but I use my token

Comment: `requests.post` does not support `form`parameter. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24834894/python-equivalent-to-curls-form-create-multipart-form-data-post-request-with) how to convert `curl`'s `--form` to Python's requests.

Answer (score 3):

solved

```
def upload_file(project_id, filename, gitlab_token):
    url = 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{0}/uploads'.format(project_id)
    headers = {'PRIVATE-TOKEN': gitlab_token}
    files = {'file': open('{0}'.format(filename), 'rb')}
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)

    if r.status_code == 200 or r.status_code == 201:
        print('Uploading the file {0}....'.format(filename))
    else:
        print('File {0} was not uploaded'.format(filename))

    markdown = r.json()['markdown']
return markdown
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Python Gitlab](https://github.com/python-gitlab/python-gitlab) package. It provides you a convenient access to the GitLab server API. The API to upload a file to a project is currently under review in a PR (https://github.com/python-gitlab/python-gitlab/pull/239)